# What to do without copper?

Tags: starbound

So the latest update to Starbound has kind of left me in a very awkward spot.  Exploring my first planet's surface, I've found an absolute abundance of Iron, a surprising smattering of silver, and an unheard-of abundance of gold!  And all of this would be great...except that I am completely understocked in Copper.

This lack of copper is not insignificant.  While I can handily make nice weapons for myself with my collection of iron, and I maybe have enough copper to construct a pick, I don't have nearly enough to create armor.

This is a problem, because every other type of metal armor relies on copper armor first.

I don't yet have enough pixels to create an iron bow to hunt very well (because the monsters are constantly killing me), so I'm in a bit of a bind.

How do I deal with this lack of essential copper early in the game?

Comment: I ran into this issue too. Very little coal, very little copper. By the time I made a copper pickaxe I already had the silver and even gold to make those pickaxes too. This ore rebalance is weird.

Comment: As of the latest patch, silver armor no longer seems to require copper armor. However, silver armor doesn't unlock until after you upgrade your ship with the Starmap Upgrade Mk 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're not also unable to find coal to use as fuel in your ship, your best bet is to simply seek another planet in the hopes that it has some richer copper deposits, particularly if you've already done a pretty good job exploring and exploiting the resources of the starting planet. There's really no reason to limit yourself to your starting planet.

However, as of the latest patch, silver armor no longer requires copper armor to be created first. It does, however, require you to have upgraded your ship with the Starmap Upgrade Mk2. The penguin mothership (which drops the molten core, which you need to create the metalworking station, which you need to make the starmap) is pretty easy to kill now and I'm certain you could do it without copper armor so long as you bring along a few bandages instead. Once that's done, skip straight to Silver armor.

Answer (score 4):

After you manage to get pixels to hunting bow, hunt animals and make leather armor set, it have same defenses as copper armor.

Use dirt blocks to make cover and hunt with bow from it.

If you have coal(in current version coal is pretty rare too), try travel to desert planet, fine sand is very easy to mine, and you can find copper ore often near surface of planet.